# Multiple transition hook globs in UI Router in AngularJS 1.6

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I created a hook to execute a function before changing page, but I need to execute this hook only for some pages.

I've found this in the documentation :

```
$transitions.onBefore({ from: 'liste.**'}, function (transition) {
        //code to execute when  the page belongs to 'liste' route
    });
```

But I need to specify more routes.

How could I do this ?

for exemple :

```
$transitions.onBefore({ from: 'liste.**', from: 'demand.**'}, function (transition) {
        //code to execute when  the page belongs to 'liste' route
    });
```

That's what I tried, but I have an error so I think this is  not the good way to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'v found a solution by my own:

```
$transitions.onBefore({ from: ['liste.**','demande.**']}, function (transition) {
    //code to execute when  the page belongs to 'liste' route
});
```

Just change the 'from' to an array